# How to best simulate IO bound work?

Tags: c#, performance, testing, io

It's easy to simulate a heavy CPU load.

```
public void ExerciseCPU()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++)
    for (int j= 0; j < 999; j++)
      for (int k = 0; k < 999; k++)
        int x = i * j * k;    
}
```

What's a comparable short code block for simulating heavy or slow IO? In other words, what's a technique for simulating a slow process that's light on the CPU?

Comment: When you ask a question like this about 'IO', it's like asking 'Can I get to Memphis?'  In other words, we need to know more about where you're going and where you're coming from. IO defines a whole Phylum of things. There's DISK I/O, Serial I/O, Sync and Async I/O, USB I/O etc etc etc.

Comment: @L.B Create 8 threads with infinite loop :)

Comment: @HamletHakobyan thanks but I know. I just wanted to show that even that can be a little bit tricky.

Comment: `thanks but I know` @L.B I thought so. This is just joke :)

Comment: @jgauffin: Sweet! When do we leave? Can I get some IO along the way?  ;)

Comment: Do you need to replicate bandwidth limitations of the IO?  In other words, if someone mocks up a few thousand web requests do you want them to end up waiting for longer than it would take them to execute the longest request, to mimic bandwith limitations, or do you only need to mimic an operation completion in a set timespan that doesn't consume CPU?  Additionally, should other, non-mocked IO on that machine be able to observe the appropriate IO device as being heavily used?  (If you need that last part, there's likely not much to do besides *actually* use the device.)

Comment: @Servy "only need to mimic an operation completion in a set timespan that doesn't consume CPU?" exactly and only this.

Comment: Then Alexei's answer is fine for you, but you should edit your question to clarify that point, for the sake of future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to test your app for long delays during IO in your mocked/intercepted IO layer:

`Thread.Sleep` will simulate non-CPU load perfectly fine for synchronous IO operations, for `async`/`await` `Task.Delay`.

```
class SlowFakeDataFromDeviceProvider : IDataFromDevice    
{
  Data GetFromDevice(...)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return ConstructFakeData();
  }
  ...
```

Note that if you actually need to have significant IO load - consider unbuffered read of a large file (to avoid memory pressure on cache).

Comment: Would there be any difference between simulating high Network IO and high file IO. Purely based on the hardware characteristics.  Maybe Ethernet handles multiple reads and writes better than hdd?  I'm trying to simulate Network IO in a multi threaded environment.

Comment: @Zapnologica I don't know. Measuring for each particular case is generally good idea.