# Add fake I/O for test

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way with .NET, I can add fake I/O for an automated test?

I saw this question: [How to best simulate IO bound work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459573/how-to-best-simulate-io-bound-work)
It's conceptually similar to what I want to do, but since I'm not measuring time in this test but actual I/O, the marked solution will not work. Essentially, I don't care what the operation is, because it's not relevant to the test, but for this test, I want actual I/O to increase, to prove that it can be tracked in the application-under-test. I say I don't care what it is, but if possible, a faster operation that instantly upped the I/O measured by the operating system would be ideal.

I'm using built-in (Windows) .NET PerformanceCounters, but I do not want to mock them out for this test - I want to know they're tracking, in this case, I/O, properly.

Test code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetCurrentIO()
    {
        _SUT.StartTrackingIO();
        long result = default;
        Parallel.Invoke(
            _SimulateIOLoad,
            () => { result = _SUT.GetCurrentIO(); }
        );
        Assert.IsTrue(result > 0, "Current IO value should be above 0");
    }
```

Comment: Which mocking framework you are using?

Comment: .NET library now has pretty good support for pipes... I suggest seeing whether those affect the performance counters you care about.  I/O on pipes occurs without requiring a disk access, so it's about as close to "instant" as you can get.

Comment: Are you specifically talking about reading/writing to disk?  How about loading a large file into a MemoryStream and then writing it to separate files and deleting them repeatedly in a loop?

Comment: @BenVoigt Could you give an example? I think what you're referring to would satisfy my use case.

Comment: @ElementalPete I haven't tried it in a loop, but writing to one file, then checking current I/O afterward returned 0, relatively consistently. Not sure if that makes any sense anyway; I might have to do the checking asynchronously.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson: There's a Microsoft-provided example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-anonymous-pipes-for-local-interprocess-communication?view=netframework-4.7.2  Note that you can create the client pipe immediately with the result of `GetClientHandleAsString()`, no need for a sub-process.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson - Yes, it would have to be async for you to check while the IO is going on.  You can use something like Task.Run to start the IO action, and then as long as you don't await the result, you should be able to move on and do other things (such as monitoring the impact) on the next line and both should take place concurrently.

Comment: @ElementalPete: That's an advantage of a pipe (assuming it counts as I/O at all) -- the write may end up in a buffer, but the read end won't complete its operation until the I/O finishes.

Comment: I'm trying to use the code from the Microsoft example in the way you mention, but either I get 0 for current I/O (PerformanceCounter("PhysicalDisk", "Disk Read Bytes/sec", "_Total")), or I get an infinite loop.

Comment: Current code using pipes:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/L7jngX

Comment: A pipe is not a physical disk read, so that's why the perf counter you're looking at is not affected. You'd need to look at the perf counter for pipes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of faking it, I went with creating a file and measuring, in a loop:

```
private long _SimulateIOLoad()
{
    long current = 0;
    while (current <= 0)
    {
        var count = 0;
        var file = Path.GetTempPath() + $"simulateIOLoad-{count}.txt";
        File.WriteAllText(file, "simulateIOLoad");
        File.Delete(file);
        current = _SUT.GetCurrentIO();
        ++count;
    }
    return current;
}
```

In my test, this proves an I/O value above 0 can be measured. This wasn't what I was initially looking for, but it works surprisingly fast.